# Autocomplete JQuery is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am NEW in JQ stuff. So basically I have a simple textbox in which I want user to search some items. I am using JQ for this. I read this link which implements this example:

http://aspnetnova.blogspot.com/2009/06/simple-jquery-ajax-server-side.html

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    .login
    {}
</style>



 <script type ="text/javascript">
   var data = "";
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tbSearch").click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "AgentList.aspx/LoadData",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   data = msg.d.split(" ");
                   $('#<%= tbSearch.ClientID %>').autocomplete(data);

               }
           });
       });
   });

    </script>    
</asp:Content>

    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server" ontextchanged="tbSearch_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
#region "Auto Complete"

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string LoadData()
    {
        return "S M SMI SM A ABC ABCD ABCI";
    }

    #endregion
```

What I am doing wrong here?